# How to get documents from collection compared with object? custom filtering function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an object:

```
{
 name: "John",
 size: 10,
 volume: 20
}
```

Documents on collection:

```
[{
 id:1,
 name: "Sara",
 size: 10
},
{
 id:2,
 volume: 20
},
{
 id:3,
 name: "John",
 size: 10
},
{
 id:4,
 size: 20
}]
```

Now I need to filter my collection using object - if every field(except id) from each document exists in object and the values are equal - then this document should be in query results:

```
[{             
 id:1,  //!EXCLUDE - name not Sara
 name: "Sara", 
 size: 10 
},
{
 id:2,  //OK - volume matches volume in object - return document in results
 volume: 20    
},
{
 id:3,  //OK - name and size matches object - return in results
 name: "John",
 size: 10
},
{
 id:4,  //!EXCLUDE - size don't match size on object
 size: 20
}]
```

So the final response would be:

```
[{
 id:2,  //OK - volume matches volume in object - return document in results
 volume: 20    
},
{
 id:3,  //OK - name and size matches object - return in results
 name: "John",
 size: 10
}]
```

How can I do it with mongo find or others? Maybe I should write my custom filtering function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

The query will select all documents where each field when exists and is equal to the value.

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [{
        $or: [{
            name: {
                $exists: false
            }
        }, {
            name: "John"
        }]
    }, {
        $or: [{
            size: {
                $exists: false
            }
        }, {
            size: 10
        }]
    }, {
        $or: [{
            volume: {
                $exists: false
            }
        }, {
            volume: 20
        }]
    }]
})
```

Comment: The problem is that I can have like 10 or more fields in Object and in each documents. In this case it would be too many combinations of $or conditions ) Maybe I can generate somehow this condition object in my js code - would it be good solution?

Comment: it looks like I would have huge number of combinations for 10 properties - each with any of others, each with any two of others and so on...

Comment: db.myCollection.find( { $where: function() { //comparing logic and return boolean result } } ); Maybe this will work, but I don't know how slow would it be...

Comment: You just have to measure performance. I'm not sure about the combinations part. If you have 10 attributes you need 10 or conditions.

Comment: for 10 attributes(a1, a2, ... a10) I would need these documents {a1}, {a1,a2}, {a1,a3}...{a1,a10}, and {a1,a2, a3}, {a1,a2, a4}...{a1,a2,...a10} and same for a2 {a2}, {a2,a3}, {a2,a4}... {a2, a10} and so on and on....

Comment: You will get all the above documents because you `$or` for existence and value followed by `$and`ing all the OR combinations together. Try running it and if it doesn't work please post an sample.

Comment: I'm not shure that I understand you code. Can you make a condition on jsfidle for 5 properties? I'll try to use it.

Comment: `db.collection.find({$and: [{
        $or: [{
            a1: {
                $exists: false
            }
        }, {
            a1: "John"
        }]
    }, {
        $or: [{
            a2: {
                $exists: false
            }
        }, {
            a2: 10
        }]
    } ...more or conditions]}` Something like this.

Comment: Looks like I get it now, thanks :) would be nice if it works, I'll check it tomorrow

Comment: It works, very nice, thank you, saved me lot of trouble ))